# Return URL image in Laravel API

Tags: json, laravel

I need to return URL path and name image from database.

This my call method to get data from database:

```
public function index(){
    $rav=Rav::select('id','image','nameravs')->get('image');
    return $this->sendResponse($rav->toArray(),'rav show is succesfuly');
}
```

Output data it look like this:

> {
>               "id": 88,
>               "image": "1579781806.png",
>               "nameravs": "asdad"
>           },

But I want to return image with path URL like this:

> "image": http://127.0.0.1:8000/images_ravs/1579781806.png

Answer (score 7):

You can use [**Eloquent Accessor**](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

add the image url attribute in **Rav.php** Model like below. then you can access it any place.

```
    public function getImageUrlAttribute($value)
    {
        return env('APP_URL'). '/images_ravs/' . $this->image;
    }
```

And don't forget to Add [**Appends**](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) property inside the `Model`

```
/**
 * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $appends = ['image_url'];
```

then you can access it like below.

```
$rav->image_url
```

Answer (score 2):

Define An Accessor in your model like this example :

```
public function getImageAttribute($value)
{
    return env('APP_URL') . Storage::url($value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function index(){
    $rav = Rav::select('id','image','nameravs')->get('image');

    return $this->sendResponse(
        [
            'id' => $rav->id,
            'image' => URL::to('/').'/images_ravs/'.rav->image,
            'nameravs' => $rev->nameravs
        ],'rav show is succesfuly');

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this: Try to use as many od Laravel's built-in functions as possible. In most cases you don't need to reinvent the wheel.

```
public function index(){
   $ravs = Rav::select('id','image','nameravs')->get();
   $results = [];

   foreach($ravs as $rav){
      $rav->image = env('APP_URL') . '/images_ravs/' . $rav->image;
      array_push($results, $rav);
   } 
   return response()->json($results);
 }
```

Comment: since ```$rav``` contains multiple Items you need to add ```foreach``` loop to add the image array values to each array.

Comment: since get will return a **Collection** and toArray will cast that collection to Array and here is the situation . if you have 10 ravs and if you need to modiy the values of each array you need ```foreach``` to iterate over the array and modify the key.

Comment: Yup that's true, I assumed having a single object, but yes I need to replace `->get()`with `->first()` but there is not `where` statement

Comment: [It is not recommended to use `env()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/configuration#configuration-caching), as in production when config is cached it will return null.  Use `config()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `selectRaw` or `select` with `DB::raw` and just `concat` that path as a prepended string infront of your `image` column in your query:

```
Rav::select(DB::raw("id, nameravs, CONCAT('/images_ravs/', image) as image"))->get()->toArray();
```

No need to include the URL (unless for some reason you have some type of CDN in front of it) in which case you can just escape the string and add it if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In the Model you can create [getAttribute](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators):

```
   public function getImageAttribute()
    {
      return $this->attributes['image'] ? URL::to('/uploads/' . $this->attributes['image']) : null; 
    }
```

Or you can create custom [casts](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#custom-casts) file:

```
    protected $casts = [
        'image' => ImageCast::class,
        'created_at' => 'datetime',
        'updated_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
```